# Python subprocess.Popen() followed by time.sleep

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I want to make a python script that will convert a TEX file to PDF and then open the output file with my document viewer.

I first tried the following:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['xelatex', '--output-directory=Alunos/', 'Alunos/' + aluno + '_pratica.tex'], shell=False,  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen(['gnome-open', 'Alunos/'+aluno+'_pratica.pdf'], shell=False)
```

This way, the conversion from TEX to PDF works all right, but, as it takes some time, the second command (open file with Document Viewer) is executed before the output file is created.

So, I tried do make the program wait some seconds before executing the second command. Here's what I've done:

```
import subprocess
import time
subprocess.Popen(['xelatex', '--output-directory=Alunos/', 'Alunos/' + aluno + '_pratica.tex'], shell=False,  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(10)
subprocess.Popen(['gnome-open', 'Alunos/'+aluno+'_pratica.pdf'], shell=False)
```

But, when I do so, the output PDF file is not created. I can't understand why. The only change was the time.sleep command. Why does it affect the Popen process?
Could anyone give me some help?

EDIT:

I've followed the advice from Faust and Paulo Bu and in both cases the result is the same.

When I run this command...

```
subprocess.call('xelatex --output-directory=Alunos/ Alunos/{}_pratica.tex'.format(aluno), shell=True)
```

... or this...

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['xelatex', '--output-directory=Alunos/', 'Alunos/' + aluno + '_pratica.tex'], shell=False,  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
```

...the Xelatex program is run but doesn't make the conversion.

Strangely, when I run the command directly in the shell...

$ xelatex --output-directory=Alunos/ Alunos/name_pratica.tex

... the conversion works perfectly.

Here's what I get when I run the subprocess.call() command:

```
$ python my_file.py 
Enter name:
name
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Alunos/name_pratica.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, loaded.
)
*
```

When I write the command directly in the shell, the output is the same, but it followed automatically by the conversion.
Does anyone know why it happens this way?

PS: sorry for the bad formating. I don't know how to post the shell output properly.

Comment: If both steps have to run synchronously, why don't you put them in the same process?

Comment: You didn't check result of the first command. Please detect a stable way to know whether it's failing. Most likely it's subprocess exit code; `p.wait()` returns it. If return value isn't 0, conversion should have failed.

Comment: Can't you automate this with a bash script? Seems like the perfect suit.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to wait the termination of the program and you are not interested in its output you should use `subprocess.call`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['xelatex', '--output-directory=Alunos/', 'Alunos/{}_pratica.tex'.format(aluno)])
subprocess.call([('gnome-open', 'Alunos/{}_pratica.pdf'.format(aluno)])
```

EDIT:

Also it is generally a good thing to use English when you have to name variables or functions.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I just did what you said, but it still doesn't work. The first command opens Xelatex, but doesn't make it create the output file as it did with Popen. Is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If `xelatex` command works in a shell but fails when you call it from Python then `xelatex` might be blocked on output in your Python code. You do not read the pipes despite setting stdout/stderr to `PIPE`. On my machine the pipe buffer is 64KB therefore if `xelatex` output size is less then it should not block.

You could redirect the output to `os.devnull` instead:

```
import os
import webbrowser
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_call

try:
    from subprocess import DEVNULL # py3k
except ImportError:
    DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w+b')

basename = aluno + '_pratica'
output_dir = 'Alunos'
root = os.path.join(output_dir, basename)
check_call(['xelatex', '--output-directory', output_dir, root+'.tex'],
           stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT)
webbrowser.open(root+'.pdf')
```

`check_call` is used to wait for `xelatex` and raise an exception on error.